# How to get number of times an event occured in clevertap?

Tags: android, clevertap

I have integrated clevertap in my android app. It is a news app which shows a number of news articles. I have created custom clevertap events for each click of an article. Now i want to know how can I create a custom event with a parameter which indicates total how many times a single article has been clicked. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Provide an example of what you have tried so far and refer on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom event for each click of the article is good enough. To see how many times a particular article has been clicked in a given time frame, you need to go to perform the following steps -

- Dashboard -> Analyze -> Events
- Then select the event that you want to analyze, and hit View Details
- Now use the Trends & Properties tab to analyze your event further
- Choose the correct "Event property" from the drop down, and look at the graphs
- Each of those graphs are clickable for further analysis

Hope this helps.

Comment: see I have 100s of articles in my app. If I create an event for each article with article name as event name than I will end up with 100s of events in the console. If I want to know no of time an article is clicked then I will have to go through all articles, which is not a good idea in my opinion. Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? @helloaanand